# Does Android 3.0 support WebSockets?

Tags: android, websocket

The question is about the default browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Android 3.0 highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html) doesn't mention anything about websockets.

Running the browser in a 3.0 AVD and going to [websocket.org - echo test](http://websocket.org/echo.html) shows:

[image]

If I go to [caniuse.com - websockets in mobile and desktop browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets), the page shows "Not supported" for Android 2.1 - 2.3.

[image: websocket browser support]

Comment: Still the case for Android browser 4.0 :-(

Comment: Android 4.1.1 native browser (samsung galaxy s3) does support websockets.

Answer (score 6):

Firefox Mobile 8 (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android#Download_Aurora) supports WebSockets protocol version 8, draft version 10. It generally behaves exactly as the desktop version. WS works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Only android 4.4 kitkat factory default browsers officially support websockets so you can NOT assume that a random device less than android 4.4 has a factory default browser that can support web-sockets As a result when you develop applications using web-view you have to take this in to account. That's why for example in Cordova you may need this [plugin](https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android) to ensure that your web-socket enabled application works in android versions less that 4.4

Answer (score 0):

No, see [browsers supporting websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets#Browsers_supporting_WebSocket)